# google domain different name server and mx records

Tags: dns, mx-record

I have a domain on google but I deployed the website for it from netlify using custom name servers. I also have a mail plan from another hosting provider that asks me to use custom mx records but I can't seem to add them. Looks like I either have custom name servers and access to the website but no access to the email or the other way around. Is there a way to make it work?

I added custom mx records under default name servers tab. The email is working but not the website.
I changed to custom name servers tab and used the name servers from netlify for the website. The website is working but then no email is sent/received